# python - more than one identical key in dict

Tags: python

this is my code

```
#this is for the max Day of a month, without leap year 
day_month = {'Janauary': 31, 'February':28, 'March':31, 'April':30, 'May':31, 'June':30, 'July':31, 'August':31, 'September':30, 'October':31, 'November':30, 'December':31}
#this dict i get as Input
myCalendar = {'April':30, 'July':10, 'May':20, 'February':29, 'August':31, 'August':13, 'August':21}
#this is the desired month to work with
month = 'August'

print(month in myCalendar) # it shows that month exists in myCalendar  
print(myCalendar[month]) # this give the value
print('')

for i in myCalendar:
    print(str(i) + ' ' + str(myCalendar[i]))
```

these are the output

```
True
21

#result of for loop
April 30
July 10
May 20
February 29
August 21  #the problem is this one, I want to have the max value of those three values
```

for August I have {'August':31, 'August':13, 'August':21} what I would like to have is the max Value 'August':31 or better {'August': [13,21,31]}

I know that in Python Dict only accepts one identical key

not allowed to use packages/libraries

can i use class?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean `getting as input` ? Because a dict can't have duplicate keys. So at the moment `myCalendar ` is created you loose 2 values over " for August

Comment: I know but the customer gives me the data ONLY like this {'April':30, 'July':10, 'May':20, 'February':29, 'August':31, 'August':13, 'August':21}

Comment: And **how** does the user gives you that data ?

Comment: Try to use a list of binary tuples instead of a dict

Comment: Are you reading this data from a file?  You need to decide how you want to represent it in Python.  If a given month may be associated with multiple dates, then you need to do something like store the data in a list, or use a dict for the month but have the dict entries be lists of days, or sets of days.  Decide how you want to represent it.

Comment: #function takes as an input a dictionary (holding monthly appointments for one year) def clean_calendar(myCalendar, month):

Comment: Perhaps https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html can help.

Comment: sorry not customer but professor

Comment: What data are you starting with and how is it represented?  It can't be represented as Python code the way you have it here in `myCalendar` because, as you've seen, that line produces a dictionary where two of the values for August are gone.  But you say that your professor gave you that code.  What does he expect you to do with it?  It looks like Python code, but it's not Python code that makes any sense.  Please clarify this point and then we can help you to move on from there.

Answer (score 0):

> what I would like to have is the max Value

to handle those types of collisions you would first check to see if the key already exists

```
if month in myCalender.keys():
```

if it does exist you would redeclare it with the max of both the inputs

```
myCalender[month] = max(myCalender[month], day_month[month] )
```

> or better {'August': [13,21,31]}

to do this you would do the same as above to check whether or  the key already exists

if it does you would then append the new value to the list inside the dict

```
myCalender[month] = list(myCalender[month]).append(day_calender[month])
```

Comment: thanks, but if i change myCalendar = {'April':30, 'July':10, 'May':20, 'February':29, 'August':23, 'August':13, 'August':21}, I should get 23 but I get 31, with the max Value I mean the max Value of a month from myCalender

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of representing your data so that it is legal Python code that preserves all of the original data:

```
myCalendar = [('April', 30), ('July',10), ('May',20), ('February',29), ('August', 31), ( 'August', 13), ('August', 21)]
```

If you do that, you can then produce the structure you want with the following code:

```
myCalendar = [('April', 30), ('July',10), ('May',20), ('February',29), ('August', 31), ( 'August', 13), ('August', 21)]

myIndex = {}
for k, v in myCalendar:
    if k not in myIndex:
        myIndex[k] = []
    myIndex[k].append(v)

print(myIndex)
```

Result:

```
{'April': [30], 'July': [10], 'May': [20], 'February': [29], 'August': [31, 13, 21]}
```

Comment: thanks alot but i get a dict like myCalendar from my professor - i have to work with it, he somehow mentioned class